# Microemu running MIDlets on JavaSE

Tags: java, java-me, emulation, midlet

I got this J2ME application (`5ud0ku.jar`) and I want to let it run on the PC with just a single JAR file (while using the JSE).

I tried using microemu, but I can't seem to get it work.

Also can the emulator be without the fake phone UI?

Comment: did you check microemu documentation at http://snapshot.microemu.org/unittests.html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found pstros to be rather nice for running JavaME stuff on Desktop computers, and it doesn't give you the fake phone UI.

http://www.volny.cz/molej/pstros/